# Need to make Tab and Accordion Plugin Accessible/Screen reader compatible

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, plugins, accessibility

I am using the following WordPress Plugins:
Accordions : https://wordpress.org/plugins/responsive-accordion-and-collapse/
Tabs: https://wordpress.org/plugins/tabs-responsive/

They are having issues being read by screenreaders. Is there code (javascript or jQuery) I can use that will make these accessibility compliant?

Below is example code of how the tabs and accordion display on the front end HTMl. Please help, I do not want to go with another accordion or tab system.

The website must be accessibility compliant.

Tabs:

```
<div id="tab_container_3998">
  <ul class="wpsm_nav wpsm_nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab_3998">
    <li role="presentation" class="">
      <a href="#tabs_desc_3998_1" aria-controls="tabs_desc_3998_1" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="false">
        <span>Tab1</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active">
      <a href="#tabs_desc_3998_2" aria-controls="tabs_desc_3998_2" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" aria-expanded="true">
        <span>Tab2</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content" id="tab-content_3998">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="tabs_desc_3998_1">
      <h1>Title 1</h1>
      <p>This is content in a tab, <a href="http://www.google.com">please read.&nbsp;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane  active animated fadeIn" id="tabs_desc_3998_2">
      <h1>Title 2</h1>
      <p>This is content in a second tab, <a href="http://www.google.com">please read.&nbsp;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Accordions:

```
<div class="wpsm_panel-group" id="wpsm_accordion_3995">
  <!-- Inner panel Start -->
  <div class="wpsm_panel wpsm_panel-default">
    <div class="wpsm_panel-heading acc-a" role="tab">
      <h4 class="wpsm_panel-title">
        <a class="" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#wpsm_accordion_3995 " href="#ac_3995_collapse1" aria-expanded="true">
          <span class="ac_open_cl_icon fa fa-minus"></span>
          <span class="ac_title_class">
            Accordion Title 1 </span>
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="ac_3995_collapse1" class="wpsm_panel-collapse collapse show in" style="" aria-expanded="true">
      <div class="wpsm_panel-body">
        <h1>Title 1</h1>
        <p>This is content in an accordion <a href="http://www.google.com">please read.&nbsp;</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Inner panel End -->
</div>
```

The screen readers don't read the accordions open or closed and don't read the second or third tabs.

Answer (score 0):

The tab code looks ok.  It follows the pattern on the "[WAI-ARIA Authoring Practices 1.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#tabpanel)".  What is not working with it?

The accordion code looks a bit wonky.  There are [accordion recommendations](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion) in the authoring practices too.  The accordion shouldn't have any "tab" roles and `aria-expanded` should only be set on the button that does the expanding.  Remove it from the accordion panel.

Both the Tab example and Accordion example should toggle the value of `aria-expanded` between true/false as the user selects the appropriate button.

Also, the tab that has `aria-expanded` set to true also needs `aria-selected` set to true.

This is all documented in the authoring practices links above.